# Anchored Unity text ...not anchoring!

Tags: unity, rendering, text

I've added some text to a unity UI and set both the achor and pivot to the top right corner as shown here:

[image]

When I start this in debug in unity the text looks fine:

[image]

What's weird is that when I build the app and run it as an executable as a host (this is a multiplayer networked game) the text also looks fine. But when I start a client instance the text doesn't appear.

I debugged and paused the game in unity in client mode and noticed that the text object is miles away from where I'm expecting it to be (and as a result doesn't show on the camera).

You can just about see the black line on the below image which is my level and the text anchored miles up and right of the level.

It seems like I've done something stupid here but I can't work out what :s

[image]

EDIT: Leo's answer was correct conceptually, but here's how I implemented the suggestion.

1. Created an empty game object `GameStateManager` in the hierarchy
2. Add a `GameState` script to the manager with a network identity
3. Added my 'RemainingTime' property to the game state script and put the [SyncVar] attribute on it
4. Put logic in the game state `Update` method to update the remaining time
5. Added a `ClientTimer` script to the text object (mono behaviour), which retrieved the `GameState` from within the clients copy of the game state manager.
6. In the update method of the client time, get a reference to the `Text` object and set the `.text` property to the value of the remaining time.

I'm not sure if this is correct, but it does seem to work, and now the `ClientTimer` script isn't networked, which resolved the issues with placement of the text.

Comment: Are you rendering mode are you using in the canvas?

Comment: The canvas is using screen space overlay. I'm willing to try any mode which gets the desired behaviour though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Screen Space, you shouldn't worry about where you see your text in the scene, as the position of the canvas elements will most likely not match the scene positions and scale, since it's using its own position and scale reference to display stuff on the screen.

But from your screenshot, you can see the canvas and the Text are disabled in the hierarchy. Since the problem is in the clients, maybe you are enabling the UI in a script that is only running in the server, or maybe you added the Network Identity component to it, and set it to "Sever only", which disables the gameObject on clients.

Comment: Hi Leo, I do have the text object causing the problem set with a network identity as I need it to be updated on the client by the server. But I've not set it to server only. I've not set it to client authority either, should I set this in a particular way?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't set anything from the UI as a network identity. I would create another gameobject with a script that keeps track of stuff that need to be networked, like the text you want to sync. This way it's easier to track errors, as you keep the display and data sync on separate modules, which makes everything easier to debug.

Comment: Leo is right , UI elements work as Viewers like in MVC pattern , you don't have to add network identity to them.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, just trying to picture the architecture. At the moment I'm seeing a server side game state, a mechanism to send the time to the client which would be networked (so a client copy of the game state?) and then some way to bind the client game state to the UI? Would this be about right?

Comment: Marking this as accepted, will edit question with final solution

Answer (score 1):

In what mode are you rendering the canvas , "Screen space overlay" or "Screen space camera" , if in camera mode you may consider that  your scene will have 2 cameras and the canvas will recognize only the host camera , so you must disable the other player camera , using unity OnClientCreate() or whatever UNET call it.

Comment: My UI canvas is using screen space overaly. What's odd is that I have a `textLabel` (which is static) and appears in the same place on each game instance. And a `textValue` which is updated within the game loop and moves on the client.